# How to make a flex element grow and shrink between two predefined width?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to make two flex elements shrink and grow, while one of their children div elements have predefined min and max widths.

If I have too much space available, I'd like my two elements to be displayed next to each other without the elements or the inner divs growing more than the max width.

If I don't have enough space available, I'd like my two inner divs to keep their min width and the flex elements to be wrapped.

My best attempt is the following:

```css
.bigcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.a {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.b {
  flex: 0 1 400px;
}

.c {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.sizedContent {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigcontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">
      a
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="sizedContent">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      c
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">
      a
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="sizedContent">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      c
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VowprJ).

The inner divs are growing and shrinking as I want them to. However there is an unwanted white space between the two because the flex element is growing as well.

Has someone a better idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the space between flex elements, switch from `display: flex` to `display: inline-flex`.

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XvWPVq)

```css
.bigcontainer {
  display: inline-flex; /* adjustment */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.a {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.b {
  flex: 0 1 400px;
}

.c {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.sizedContent {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  height: 15px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigcontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="sizedContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="a">a</div>
    <div class="b">
      <div class="sizedContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately if you do that the width of the coloured divs remains at 200px and is not growing to 400px anymore.